# how to store data permanently in listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

i use this (link or code) to store id and password of user 
http://techblogon.com/android-login-registration-screen-with-sqlite-database-example/

problem is i want to store list view item permanently in my listview when user login against their account

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private String currentImageName = "ic_launcher";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_ad_layout);

    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveAdd);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button buttonaddimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddImage);
    buttonaddimage.setOnClickListener(this);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want Create a new Add?")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Create_adds_Activity.this, Button_mak.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.buttonAddImage:

        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


        break;
    case R.id.buttonSaveAdd:
        EditText editTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        EditText editTextDes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
        EditText editTextOwner = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOwnerName);
        EditText editTextOwnerEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOwnerEmail);
        EditText editTextPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPrice);

        //populating data object from the values received 
        //from view
        String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString(); 
        String description = editTextDes.getText().toString();
        String ownerName = editTextOwner.getText().toString();
        String ownerEmail = editTextOwnerEmail.getText().toString();
        String pricce = editTextPrice.getText().toString();
        Advertisement  object = new Advertisement(title, description,
                ownerName, ownerEmail, currentImageName, Integer.parseInt(pricce), 100);
        Button_mak.ads.add(object);

        this.finish();
        break;



    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView10 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.creatae);
        imageView10.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        currentImageName = ">>>"+picturePath;

    }
```

i use array adapter

```
    final Context context = this;
public static ArrayList<Advertisement> ads = new ArrayList<Advertisement>();
```

Comment: `i want to store list view item permanently in my listview`. A ListView is not a permanent data holder. It only **shows** data **temporarily**. You always have to fill it reading the data from (for instance) a database. But it could be a text file or an xml (which is a structured text file). Or a csv (which is a semi-structured text file).

Answer (score 0):

I would deffenitely recommend using SQLite to save your data.
In the beginning it might seem a bit complex, but when ur used to it, its an ease.

Here's a handy little tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: i want to store listview data with image in database.....suggest me some link plzzz

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html - here is all the available storage options in the android libary, i guess i would use sql for the strings and ints and another option for the pictures, its just to start googeling :-P